# MPI only recognising 1 process in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi

I am learning MPI for parallel programming in C and I am using a processor with 4 cores. I am trying to do an example from a tutorial in which the output should be:

```
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 4 processes
Hello world! I'm process 2 out of 4 processes
Hello world! I'm process 1 out of 4 processes
Hello world! I'm process 3 out of 4 processes
```

In whatever order.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int ierr, num_procs, my_id;
  ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

  printf("Hello world! I'm process %i out of %i processes\n", my_id, num_procs);
  ierr = MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I compile it using:

```
mpicc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

And I run it using:

```
mpirun -np 4 helloworld
```

This is what is outputted:

```
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
```

It's outputting it 4 times which is relatively good news I guess but the program isn't recognising the number of threads and each thread ID.

Is it even running in parallel or is it just running 4 times in serial?
How can I get the program to recognise the amount of threads and the thread ID properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which MPI library are you using?

Comment: mpich. The library I got via sudo apt-get mpich. I haven't done anything with it besides that. @arash

Comment: Please, check that `mpirun` which you used is really from the same MPI library mpich (which provides mpicc), and not from openmpi. (mpich has `mpiexec`, openmpi has `mpirun`; set of environment variables used by scripts is different, so mpirun can't assure program that it is in parallel start).

Comment: How do I do that? I am really new to MPI and parallel programming in general and I can't find anywhere that teaches me how to set it up. I've also tried mpiexec with the same parameters but it yields the same result

Comment: in a terminal: `mpirun --version` should give you some info

Comment: Okay, done that. mpirun IS OpenMPI and mpiexec is OpenRTE. How do I get the matching compiler/executer?

Comment: @JoelMiller, what is your OS? Is it debian/ubuntu? Always check that mpicc and mpirun (or mpiexec) used for the program are the same. You may check mpicc/mpirun/mpiexec files with package manager to find what is the package (`dpkg -S /usr/bin/mpirun`). Some debian/ubuntu may have alternatives (https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives; https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=579307) to dynamically switch mpi implementations; and clusters usually have `module` command to switch environments (http://modules.sourceforge.net/ or Lmod).  Easiest way is to delete openmpi package.

Answer (score 0):

```
mpicc helloworld.c -o helloworld

mpirun -np 4 helloworld

Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
```

This sequence clearly shows us that your MPI runtime was unable to detect parallel start, it probably from misconfiguration: your `mpicc` is from one MPI implementation and your `mpirun` is from other. For example, both MPICH and OpenMPI have `mpicc` scripts for compiling MPI programs, but their `mpiexec`/`mpirun` programs are incompatible. Compile with MPICH, start with OpenMPI starter and MPICH runtime will not receive needed environment variables to figure out parallel run and its parameters.

You should revisit list of installed packages (`dpkg -l|egrep 'mpich|openmpi'`) and check which file is from which library (`dpkg -L mpich`, `dpkg -L openmpi-bin`; `dpkg -L libmpich-dev`, `dpkg -L libopenmpi-dev`). Ubuntu/debian also have system of "alternatives" which will install symbolic links `mpicc` and `mpirun` to actual scripts (do `ls -l /usr/bin/mpicc /usr/bin/mpirun` to see current state of the links). Check `update-alternatives` tool, its [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) and [docs](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) to learn how to reset all mpi-named scripts to one implementation (and there is `galternatives` GUI for it).

According to file lists in packages, mpich and openmpi have variants of mpirun/mpiexec with suffixes http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/openmpi-bin/filelist http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/mpich/filelist:

```
/usr/bin/mpiexec.openmpi
/usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
/usr/bin/mpiexec.hydra
/usr/bin/mpiexec.mpich
/usr/bin/mpirun.mpich
```

Same situation for mpicc scripts: http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/libopenmpi-dev/filelist http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/libmpich-dev/filelist

```
/usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi
/usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
```

Always use mpicc and mpirun (or mpiexec) from the same implementation. You may also use variants with suffix to be sure: `mpicc.openmpi` & `mpiexec.openmpi` pair or `mpicc.mpich` & `mpiexec.mpich` pair.

And to use some MPI implementation, you should have it fully installed, both for bin, lib and dev packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows with the MS-MPI v10.1.3 from June 2023 and I solved by using the previous version MS-MPI v10.1.2 from November 2019.
This is the code I am using:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

int my_rank;
int world_size;

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

std::cout << "Hello World from process " << my_rank << " out of " << world_size << " processes!!!" << std::endl;

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

And this is the result from mpiexec -n 6 helloWorld.exe:

```
Hello World from process 1 out of 6 processes!!!
Hello World from process 2 out of 6 processes!!!
Hello World from process 5 out of 6 processes!!!
Hello World from process 3 out of 6 processes!!!
Hello World from process 0 out of 6 processes!!!
Hello World from process 4 out of 6 processes!!!
```